# Can a perspective be closed in Eclipse without its layout being reset?

Tags: eclipse

I use Eclipse for multiple programming languages: C, Java, Scala, Clojure, Perl Python etc...
I have customized the layout each of the perspective. Whenever I close a perspective (right click perspective -> close), and open it again, my customized layout is gone and the default layout appears.

Is there a way to close perspective without resetting its layout?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the perspective (windows>save perspective as). The custom layout is saved in the metadata in your workspace. If you start a new workspace you need to either copy your metadata or you will need to redo your customizing.

Answer (score 0):

Curious. Mine are preserved, both when moving from perspective to perspective in a session, and when opening and closing Eclipse. I suspect you've set some default behavior value that says to always load the original perspective (resetting). Check Preferences/General/Perspectives.

There IS a way to save a customized perspective, in the Window dropdown.

I'm not an Eclipse expert by any means. Why not ask over at the Eclipse Newcomers forum?
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/
They've been very helpful.